Why am I getting Runtime exception at 0x004000e8: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001004a
.data
.align 2                # Align the next data item on a word boundary
intArr:             .space 28            # Array to hold integers (7 \* 4 bytes)
vtdPrompt:          .asciiz "vals to do? "
entIntPrompt:       .asciiz "enter an int: "
adjMsg:             .asciiz " is bad, make it "
origLab:            .asciiz "original:\\n"
backLab:            .asciiz "backward:\\n"
dmPrompt:           .asciiz "do more? "
invalid_input_msg:  .asciiz "Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.\\n"

.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4            # syscall code for printing string
la $a0, vtdPrompt    # load the address of the prompt
syscall

    li $v0, 4            # syscall code for printing string
    la $a0, origLab      # load the address of the original label prompt
    syscall

main_loop:
jal GetOneIntByVal   # call GetOneIntByVal to get valsToDo
move $t0, $v0        # move valsToDo to $t0

    li $a1, 1            # load minInt
    li $a2, 7            # load maxInt
    la $a3, adjMsg       # load address of the message
    jal ValidateInt      # call ValidateInt to validate valsToDo
    
    # Check for zero input before proceeding
    beq $t0, $zero, exit_program   # exit loop if valsToDo is 0
    
    # Initialize loop variables
    move $t1, $zero      # Initialize i to 0
    move $t2, $t0        # Initialize j to valsToDo

swap_loop:
beq $t1, $t2, show_backwards   # exit loop if i equals (valsToDo - 1)

    sll $t4, $t1, 2         # calculate offset for intArr[i]
    add $t3, $t4, $gp       # add offset to base address of intArr
    lw $a0, 0($t3)          # load intArr[i]
    
    addi $t4, $t2, -1    # calculate (valsToDo - 1)
    sll $t5, $t4, 2      # calculate offset for intArr[j]
    add $t5, $t5, $gp    # add offset to base address of intArr
    lw $a1, 0($t5)       # load intArr[j]
    
    jal SwapTwoInts      # call SwapTwoInts to swap intArr[i] and intArr[j]
    
    addi $t1, $t1, 1     # increment index i
    addi $t2, $t2, -1    # decrement index j
    j swap_loop

show_backwards:
move $a0, $t0        # move valsToDo to $a0
jal ShowIntArray     # call ShowIntArray to show reversed array

    li $v0, 4            # syscall code for printing string
    la $a0, dmPrompt     # load the address of the prompt
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 12           # syscall code for reading character
    syscall
    lb $a0, 0($v0)       # load the byte read
    
    li $t6, 'n'          # load 'n' into $t6
    li $t7, 'N'          # load 'N' into $t7
    beq $a0, $t6, exit_program   # exit loop if character is 'n'
    beq $a0, $t7, exit_program   # exit loop if character is 'N'
    
    j main_loop 

exit_program:
li $v0, 10           # syscall code for exit
syscall

# Function to get an integer by value

# Arguments:

# $a0: Address of the prompt

# Returns:

# $v0: The integer entered by the user

GetOneIntByVal:
li $v0, 5            # syscall code for reading integer
syscall

    # Check if the input is a valid integer
    bltz $v0, invalid_input  # If the input is negative, it's invalid
    j input_valid             # Otherwise, input is valid

input_valid:
jr $ra                  # Return if the input is valid

invalid_input:
\# Print an error message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, invalid_input_msg
li $v0, 11           # syscall code for printing character
li $a0, '\\n'         # load newline character to print
syscall

    # Re-prompt the user to enter an integer
    j GetOneIntByVal

# Function to validate an integer

# Arguments:

# $a0: Address of the integer to validate

# $a1: Minimum allowed value

# $a2: Maximum allowed value

# $a3: Address of the message

ValidateInt:
lw $t0, 0($a0)       # load the integer to validate
blt $t0, $a1, less_than_min
bgt $t0, $a2, greater_than_max

    jr $ra               # return if the integer is within range

less_than_min:
\# Handle less than min
j set_min

greater_than_max:
\# Handle greater than max
j set_max

set_min:
sw $a1, 0($a0)       # set the integer to the minimum value
jr $ra               # return to caller

set_max:
sw $a2, 0($a0)       # set the integer to the maximum value
jr $ra               # return to caller

# Function to show an array of integers

# Arguments:

# $a0: Address of the array

# $a1: Size of the array

# $a2: Address of the label

ShowIntArray:
li $v0, 4            # syscall code for printing string
move $a0, $a2        # load the address of the label
syscall

    li $t0, 0            # initialize index k to 0

show_loop:
beq $t0, $a1, end_show   # exit loop if k equals size

    lw $t1, 0($a0)       # load the integer at array[k]
    li $v0, 1            # syscall code for printing integer
    move $a0, $t1        # load the integer to print
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 11           # syscall code for printing character
    li $a0, ' '          # load space character to print
    syscall
    
    addi $a0, $a0, 4     # move to the next integer in the array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1     # increment index k
    j show_loop

end_show:
li $v0, 11           # syscall code for printing character
li $a0, '\\n'         # load newline character to print
syscall

    jr $ra               # return to caller

# Function to swap two integers

# Arguments:

# $a0: Address of the first integer

# $a1: Address of the second integer

SwapTwoInts:
lw $t0, 0($a0)       # load the first integer
lw $t1, 0($a1)       # load the second integer

    sw $t1, 0($a0)       # store the second integer at the first address
    sw $t0, 0($a1)       # store the first integer at the second address
    
    jr $ra               # return to caller

It gives me that error. What should I do?

Debug it.  There's one instruction that is faulting / causing an exception. Usually when an instruction faults, it is either a wrong instruction, or more often that instruction has been given bad data to work with.  So, sometimes that instruction needs to be fixed and other times an earlier instruction is wrong or missing, but the fault / exception is not detected until later.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
